# IntelliJ Idea - How to generate java code by selected variable

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I tried to get a solution from google but failed. Seems nobody did this.

**Background**
I am automation engineer and I am writing some page-model based java class for our business.

Like following -

```
public class PersonalCenterPage extends BasePage {
     MyWebElement button1;
}
```

Here `button1` is a element from specific webpage. Generally I must define some common methods for it such as click, verify or wait for, like following:

```
public void click_button1(){
    button1.click();
}
```

There are many elements that I must write common methods for them, which would take so much time.

**What I did by eclipse**

While using eclipse, I can write a code template called "common" which contains all those common methods. When I want to automatically generate the "methods suit", I can select the variable "button1", press "alt + /" and choose "common" in the displayed list.

**So how could I implement the same thing by using IntelliJ Idea?**

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why don't you use OOP constructs like inheritance instead of using IDE templates?

Comment: I think you're looking for "Live Templates"

Comment: @shmosel thanks. This might be another good way. But I must consider if it's suitable here, in my project.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah I've checked "Live Templates" but it can not support what I want, at least I don't know how to "choose a variable then generate code".

Answer (score 0):

In Intelliji, You can achieve this using File and Code Template option, also live template option.

Open Settings/Preferences dialog and under the Editor node, select File and Code Templates page. More details here 
[File and Code Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/creating-and-editing-file-templates.html#d1891173e15)